# In Haskell how do I get the number of bytes in a UTF8 string?

Tags: string, haskell, character-encoding

Say I have the UTF8 string `"Hello Snowman ☃!"`. It has 16 characters and takes up 18 bytes. How can I get haskell to show me the number of bytes this string takes up?

I've tried using Data.ByteArray, Data.Text, ByteString and in each case I have come up short.

Comment: A string does not take up `x` bytes (unless you mean in Haskell memory, but I'm pretty sure you don't, in which case, this string certainly doesn't take up 18 bytes). A string *in a particular encoding* takes up `x` bytes. Indeed, encoded as UTF8 string, `"Hello Snowman ☃!"` takes up 18 bytes. However, a Haskell `String` doesn't have an encoding. Encode the string in your preferred encoding and compute the length of the encoded expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the excellent [utf8-string](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string) package for this.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.UTF8 as UTF8

numBytesUtf8 :: String -> Int
numBytesUtf8 = BS.length . UTF8.fromString
```

Then, to use your example,

```
ghci> numBytesUtf8 "Hello Snowman ☃!"
18
```

Of course, you should probably not be doing this in the first place. `UTF8.fromString` and `BS.length` are probably the functions you want to use, but your strings probably ought to be *already* bytestrings for you to be interested in how many bytes it takes to encode them as such.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have also had luck now with `Data.ByteArray.length` after I used `Data.Text.pack` and `encodeUtf8` from Data.Text.Encoding. That also has given me the right value. Yours seems more succinct though.

Comment: In my case it was important to realize that `Data.ByteString.length` returns the number of bytes whereas `Data.ByteString.UTF8.length` returns the number of *characters*. Easy to mix them up.