# Can we write a function in Haskell to measure the number of bytes that a string of n characters occupies?

Tags: haskell, byte, heap-memory

Suppose I have the string

```
"abc"
```

and I want to calculate the number of bytes it occupies in memory.

I could do:

```
import Data.Bits
finiteBitSize ("abc" :: [Char])
```

but that breaks because `[Char]` is not a type supported by the function. (Also it is bits not bytes, but the point was to paint a picture of what I'm looking for).

My question is: **Can we write a function in Haskell to measure the number of bytes that a string of n characters occupies?**

Comment: A `String` is a *linked list* of `Char`s, so you have the data (in the `Char`s) but the linked list structure will occupy space as well. Furthermore note that due to laziness, it is not said that the `String` *at that moment* takes the size of the sum of the size of the caracters.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44876904/67579

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a Haskell package called `ghc-datasize` which allows you to calculate **real** occupied memory by every Haskell value. You can even see an example of how to calculate string size in the official Hackage documentation:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-datasize

To calculate the length of the `String` you need to use the following function:

```
recursiveSize :: a -> IO Word
```

It looks like this:

```
ghci> recursiveSize $!! "foobar"
240
```

Comment: Could you expand on the link of the example?

Comment: @hawkeye I've added an example.

Answer (score 13):

It's complicated.

Let's talk about GHC, and about `String` specifically, and let's assume the thing has been fully evaluated, so we didn't get to use it iteratively in a GC-friendly way and we didn't get to delay evaluation and store a tiny thunk representing an enormous data structure.

After making all those simplifying assumptions, we're gonna need to know some definitions.

```
type String = [Char]
data [a] = [] | a : [a] -- pseudosyntax
data Char = C# Char# -- I'm guessing, couldn't find a canonical source
```

Now we're going to use a few rules of thumb. First: unboxed stuff (like `Char#`) is generally stored in a machine word. We live in a world of 64-bit machines, so `Char#` is probably 8 bytes, even though it likely only uses the bottom 4 bytes of it. Second: data constructors are a word to say which constructor, plus a word to point at each of the fields.

Now we're ready to tot it up.

Empty strings are `[]`, one word for the constructor, no words for fields, so one word total.

Nonempty strings are `c : cs`, so one word for the `:` constructor, one word to point to `c`, one word to point to `cs`, one word for the `C#` constructor, one word for the `Char#`.  That's 5 words plus however many we need for `cs`.

So for a `String` of length n, we've got 5*n words to represent the body of the `String` and one extra for the terminating `[]`. Practically speaking that's 40 bytes per character! Yikes.

And now you know why packed representations like `Text` (or, when appropriate, `ByteString`) are such a big deal.

Comment: `Char` is defined pretty much like that in [`GHC.Types`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/GHC-Types.html#t:Char). The only extra bit is a `CTYPE` annotation.

Comment: Does GHC preallocate common ASCII `Char` values the way it does small `Int` values?

Comment: @dfeuer Ah, I bet it does! And the reason I bet this is that I found on another question (which I am having trouble finding now) that the estimate constructed as in this answer was too high compared to my observations of max residency; sharing of small `Char`s could perhaps have explained that discrepancy.

Comment: @dfeuer Some simple testing seems to support that hypothesis: `readFile "foo" >>= \s -> print (length s) >> print (length s)` takes about double the max residency if `foo` has `'\1114111'`s in it than if it has `'a'`s in it.

Comment: (...and "about double max residency" is consistent with saving 2 words out of 5 for each character, which is what you would predict if the `C#` constructor and `Char#` content cost nothing.)

Comment: Yes, ghc does preallocate ASCII Chars and ensure sharing during GC. Both that and the small Int trick is stuff it inherited from hbc.